# google app script timed trigger delayed than scheduled

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I tried to create a trigger that was 10 seconds later relative to the current time, but in fact the trigger was only triggered after nearly 1 minute。

trigger create code:

```
var trigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger('groupMediaAgencyTest').timeBased().after(10000).create();
```

trigger triggered log:

```
groupMediaAgencyTest    触发器 2020年12月2日下午6:33:33 0.766 秒     
doPost  网络应用    2020年12月2日下午6:32:37 1.294 秒
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Apps Script trigger execution too late](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58394838/google-apps-script-trigger-execution-too-late)

Answer (score 1):

There's no guarantee that the time trigger will be exact. This is indicated in multiple places:

[`.after()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#after(Integer))

> The actual duration might vary, but won't be less than your specified minimum.

[Time-drive triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)

> The time may be slightly randomized — for example, if you create a recurring 9 a.m. trigger, Apps Script chooses a time between 9 a.m. and 10 a.m.

Comment: thanks,i got it,so does exists any way to create a trigger accurate to the sencod ?

Comment: I don't think so @Victor